# How can i show custum price for a specific product type in magento

Tags: magento

I have added a custom product type in magento and i have also created a custom attribute for this product type.Now i want product should be sold on what the value is given in custom attribute.

suppose product price is $100 and i have given $120 value in custom attribute.Now the product should be sold in $120 instead $100.
I don't want to use special price and also don't want to update the product price as well.any guide line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats possible, you can set a custom price.
Get a item from the qoute and call the following:

```
/* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
$item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Here you can find more detailed informations
http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/add-an-item-to-the-cart-with-a-custom-price-in-magento/